# VLOOKUP conditional formatting isn't working

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

When I input this:

`=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("RC",FALSE), nodes!C3:C, 2, false)`

It says: "invalid formula"

I'm not sure what's going on?

I've tried changing the search string to a different string as well and it still doesn't work. I've tried changing the search range to one currently on the sheet - still no dice.

EDIT

So I'm trying to use conditional formatting if the value is found on another sheet. I've changed my formula to this:

`COUNTIF(nodes!C3:C,INDIRECT("RC",false))`

But it's still not working.

Comment: Nevermind. I realized you're not supposed to put the `=` in front for conditional formulas. The error message google sheets gave was completely idiotic.

Comment: Even so, it's still not working?

Comment: No, normally you do use an `=` sign for the custom formula for conditional formatting.  And if you share your sheet, someone will be sure to help you with that.

Comment: But I don't believe that conditional formatting can refer to another sheet/tab directly.  You could cheat, and mirror that other data on some hidden columns in this sheet, and then your conditional formatting formula should work.  Or the `INDIRECT` suggested by iansedano may work (not sure), and named ranges can also be used.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your sheet so I am not sure how exactly to construct the formula but this example may help:

```
=INDIRECT("nodes!"&CELL("address", C3))="RC"
```

Or if you could share your sheet so I can understand a bit better what you are after.